# Why is my trait boot not called?

Tags: laravel

In my phpunit test I'm updating values:

```
/** @test */
public function it_updates_newsletter_when_user_privacy_is_updated() 
{

    $privacy = create('App\UserPrivacy', ['user_id' => auth()->id()]);

    $privacy->update(['firstname' => 'Philipp']);

}
```

And I'm trying to catch the updated event in a trait. But the thing is, it is never beeing called. Here is the trait:

```
trait UpdatesNewsletter
{
    /**
     * Boot the trait.
     */
    protected static function bootUpdatesNewsletter()
    {
        if (auth()->guest()) return;

        static::updated(function ($model){
            var_dump('is called by trait');
        });

    }
}
```

Just for my sanity check, I wrote the event catch for the model itself.

```
class UserPrivacy extends Model
{
    use UpdatesNewsletter;

     /**
      * Boot the model.
      */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::updated(function ($privacy){
            var_dump('is called by class');
        });
    }
}
```

And in my console I see the only message:

```
string(18) "is called by class"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try making the trait function public?

Comment: I'd guess that `auth()->guest()` is returning `true`. Put a `dd(auth()->guest())` before the check in your trait's boot method.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, somehow I don't have the session of auth, only in that case.

```
protected static function bootUpdatesNewsletter()
{
    static::updated(function ($model){
        if (auth()->guest()) return;   // at this point you have access to auth()->user etc
        var_dump('is called by trait');
    });

}
```